# Flow field generated by a sphere in fluid

Tags: flow, navier-stokes

What is a flow field generated by a swimming sphere in the fluid? (in low reynolds regime)? What is the flow field generated by a swimming cylinder in this regime? 
It seems that the question is not clear. So I try to make it better: when an active sphere is moving in a liquid. What is the solution of Stokes equation for flow in the liquid? If an active cylinder is moving in the fluid, what is the solution?

Comment: It's a little odd that no one could answer my question! Is it unclear?

Comment: Yes, the question is unclear. What is it you are asking for? What do you mean by "swimming"? What is the motion of your cylinder or sphere? When you say "low-Re regime", are you asking for a Stokes solution (Limit for $Re\rightarrow0$)? Are you asking for an algebraic expression giving the (2D/3D?) velocity field? For the sphere, is [this](http://web.mit.edu/1.63/www/Lec-notes/chap2_slow/2-5Stokes.pdf]) what you are looking for?

Comment: By the way, the case of the cylinder happens to be tricky, see the [Wikipedia article here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_flow). It turns out there is no non-trivial solution for the Stokes equations around an infinitely long cylinder, a fact known as *Stokes' Paradox*.

Comment: I edited the question. The first link doesn't work. (The error is file not found.)  what about a short cylinder? @Pirx

Comment: [Corrected link](http://web.mit.edu/1.63/www/Lec-notes/chap2_slow/2-5Stokes.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

See [Pirx link in comments](http://web.mit.edu/1.63/www/Lec-notes/chap2_slow/2-5Stokes.pdf). [Recommended book: "Low Reynolds number hydrodynamics"](http://www.springer.com/gb/book/9789024728770). 
Answer for a sphere from [this derivation](http://cbp.tnw.utwente.nl/PolymeerDictaat/node39.html#eq:hydro:35):

$$ \vec u(\vec r) = \vec v \frac{3R}{4r} (1 + \frac{R^2}{3r^2}) + \vec r\, (\vec v \cdot \vec r) \, \frac{3R}{4r^3} \, (1 - \frac{R^2}{r^2}) $$

where $\vec v$ is spheres velocity.